# Calculate PMF for a fair coin tossed 10 times

Tags: r

A fair coin is tossed 10 times. Find the Probability Mass Function (PMF) of X and the length of the longest run of heads observed. Need to write R code to accomplish this task. Following are some of the functions to use for this task:
`as.integer()`, `intToBits()`, `rev()`, `rle()`.

I have the starting idea of the function to use, but do not have sufficient knowledge to tie it together to calculate the PMF and calculate the length of the longest run.

```
toBinary <- function(n){
  paste0(as.integer(rev(intToBits(n)[1:10])),collapse = "")
}
toBinary(4)
toBinary(1023)

for(i in 0:1023){
  print(toBinary(i))
}
```

Comment: it is your answer: `dbinom(0:10, 10, 0.5)` from zero to ten heads. Do you must write a random experiment, that is, a function that generates random values not a distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following lines to complete the task:

```
# number of trials
trials <- 10
# probability of success
success <- 0.5
# x is number of random variable X
x <- 0:trials
# number of probabilities for a binomial distribution
prob <- dbinom(x,trials,success)
prob

# create a table with the data from above
prob_table<-cbind(x,prob)
prob_table
# specify the column names from the probability table
colnames(prob_table)<-c("x", "P(X=x)")
prob_table
```